# Solution to ODE with Dirac Delta satisfies ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, dirac-delta

I am working on a problem where I have the following ODE. $$m\dot{v}+bv=\delta_I(t)$$
where
$$\delta_I(t)=\begin{cases}0, & \text{for}&t\ne0\\ I, & \text{for} &t=0\end{cases}.$$
The solution $v(t)$ was derived using Laplace transforms, the ODE in the Laplace domain is (with $0$ initial conditions)$$(ms+b)V(s)=I$$ giving $$v(t)=\frac{I}{m}e^{-bt/m}.$$
How does this solution satisfy the original ODE though? At $t\ne0$ everything is good,$$-\frac{Ib}{m}e^{-bt/m}+\frac{Ib}{m}e^{-bt/m}=0,$$ while at $t=0$, $$-\frac{Ib}{m}+\frac{Ib}{m}=I$$ the result seems to be saying $0=1$ which is obviously false. What am I missing here?

Comment: You don't seem to have included the dirac Delta in solving the equation. You should solve the homogeneous eqn first and then find the inhomogeneous part using say variation of parameters or a Laplace or Fourier transform. http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%2By%3Ddirac+delta

Comment: The dirac Delta is the RHS of the very first equation. The problem is using an impulse of magnitude $I$. The final solution was obtained using Laplace transforms.

Comment: I meant that your solution didn't seem to have any term that would lead to a dirac Delta on the right hand side. Let me check and see if I can find a solution.

Comment: It is possible I made a mistake

Comment: In your second displayed equation, the $I$ should be $Ie^{-t}.$

Comment: @B.Goddard that's not an impulse or Dirac delta though?

Comment: I was guessing that by $\delta_I(t)$ you meant the the delta function with mass $I$ at $t=0.$

Comment: It's meant to be an impulse with magnitude $I$ in the problem statement, did I write it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I start by find the solution to the homogeneous eqn: $$my'+by=0 \to y_h=Ce^{-bt/m}$$

Then, we can determine the inhomogeneous part using a Fourier transform of the original eqn: $$my'+by=\delta(t) \to i\omega m \tilde{y}+b\tilde{y}=1 \to \tilde{y}=\frac{1}{m}\frac{1}{b/m+i\omega}$$

From a table of Fourier transforms $$\frac{1}{b/m+i\omega} \to \theta(t)e^{-bt/m}$$ where $\theta(t)$ is the [heaviside step function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

So, $f_i= \theta(t)e^{-bt/m}/m$, which when combined with the homogeneous solution will give the general solution for this differential equation.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this method before for similar problems. Can you say what I'm doing wrong with the Laplace transform?

Comment: @NWernerC456 The Laplace transform is defined for t greater than or equal to zero. For this range of t, $\theta(t)=1$, which is the result you got. To include t less than zero, you need to replace the implicit 1 in front of your solution with $\theta(t)$, which will give you the same inhomogeneous part as in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why you got a wrong answer is because this ODE isn’t properly defined at t=0. The dirac delta function itself is singular at t=0. So is the ODE at t=0, holding no responsibility for t=0. The ODE only cares about the solution at t>0,. The only piece of precise info the dirac delta provides is that its time integral is 1.